# Страница не растягивается на полный экран

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Начал пробовать стилизовать страницы в React, и столкнулся с проблемой, что компонент страницы прижимается к левому краю экрана, и остальное пространство не заполняется стилями.

И получается такая вот картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам не понял в чем проблема, в стилях, или в самом React

Вот сам класс компонента:

```
export default class NotFound extends Component {
    static NotFoundComponent() {
        return (
            <div className="error-container">
                <div className="error-code">
                    <h1>404</h1>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="error-description">
                    <h2>Page not found</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="divider"></div>
                <Link to="/" className="main-button">
                    Back to main page
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {NotFound.NotFoundComponent()}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Вот файл со стилями NotFound.css:

```
.error-container {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.error-code h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
}

.main-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.error-description h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: gray;
    flex: 1;
}

.divider {
    width: 80px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Вот файл index.css:

```
:root {
  font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;

  color-scheme: light dark;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  background-color: #242424;

  font-synthesis: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #646cff;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #535bf2;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-color 0.25s;
}
button:hover {
  border-color: #646cff;
}
button:focus,
button:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    color: #213547;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: #747bff;
  }
  button {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в глобальных стилях React, а именно в файле index.css

Не могу сказать точно почему это таким образом влияло, но если в **body**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    /*display: flex;*/
    place-items: center;
    min-width: 320px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Закоментировать стиль **display: flex;** то все нормализуется

Возможно это не самое лучшее решение проблемы, но пока что только такое нашел.

Comment: Вместо этого используйте `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: @ИванИпатов Ноль эффекта